# Problem with consecutive cin's

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x ;  
    cin >> y ;   // This gets ignored
}
```

Hi 
in above prog after pressing Ctrl-D during first cin second cin gets ignored. how i can make second cin work after pressing ctr-D during first cin. cin.ignore() and cin.clear() doesn;t seem to work.

My question is that if im pressing ctrl-D during first cin bascially i am leaving eof char in i/p stream which is not going to be read and it reamins there. now can't i remove this character from the stream so that it's  ready again for input. if not what's the exact reason behind it.

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl-D` is for **end-of-file**. In this case, it indicates the end of the `stdin`stream, which means nothing is to be read again.

Comment: same things happnes if i press a character during first cin.

Comment: @user:  you have declared the type to be read in as `int`.  If you input a `char` and call `cin.good()`, you'll notice it returns false - meaning your input stream is no longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing Ctrl+D signals that you have reached the end of input (end of file). That obviously means that the next input operation doesn't even have to try, because there can't be anything more to read.

If you don't want to terminate the input stream, just don't press Ctrl+D!

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-D signals the end of transmission or end of file.  Using it will prevent all further reads from the standard input (`std::cin` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

For safer more robust and reliable code **always** check the stream state before and after reading, especially after reading.

An example code fragment:

```
int x;
int y;

int main(void)
{
    if (!(cin >> x))
    {
        cerr << "Error reading first value." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (!(cin >> y))
    {
        cerr << "Error reading second value." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "First number: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Second number: " << y << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Remember that a read may fail for other reasons than EOF.**  In your case the `"cin >> x"` may fail because the user entered something that is not a number, such as a letter or symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: When you found the EOF, reset the stream with

```
clear(eofbit)
```

I know you said you tried

```
clear()
```

but that makes me assume that you called it without parameters which defaults to:

```
clear(goodbit)
```

Comment: Calling clear with goodbit (or with no parameters) should still clear the EOF flag.

Comment: Pressing ^D closes the file handle for `stdin`... this is way below the library level and no application can work around this. It's just as final `echo 1 | some_app` where `some_app` tries `int a,b; if (std::cin >> a >> b) ...`: there isn't a b and never will be... you can perhaps make the *C++ istream object* forget that it already knows the stream is closed, but next time it tries to read from it it will then just rediscover that... the operation can never succeed.

Comment: so does it mean that only way is to run the program again